# Audio Analysis in WinJS

Tags: javascript, audio, signal-processing, windows-store-apps, audio-analysis

I've been poking around [the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) to find what I'm looking for, as well as searching online (but examples of Windows Store apps are pretty scarce).  What I'm essentially looking for is a starting point for analyzing audio in a Windows Store JavaScript app.  If I were creating a simple visualizer, for example, and I need to detect the various kinds of "bumps" in the currently playing audio.

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?  Is this something that's even possible in a Windows Store JavaScript app?  Whether it's the audio of a selected song, or the device's currently playing song, or the audio on the microphone... either way is fine for my needs at the moment.  I'm just looking for where to start in the analysis of the audio.

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer your question, but [this article](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2012/06/music-developer-on-windows-8-a-leap-forward-for-desktops-a-leap-backward-for-metro-winrt/) is a good read.

Comment: @GGG: Interesting read, for sure.  WinRT is definitely a subset of the APIs we've enjoyed in the industry for years, and I think it's going to take a few revisions for it to mature into something truly compelling.  I actually like some aspects of the paradigm shift, but Microsoft isn't known for making a polished product right out of the gate and it shows.  But if the limitations extend to the point that even a simple audio visualizer is out of its reach, that's going to hit hard.  (Well, it _would_ hit hard if the platform was relevant in the market, which so far it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

GGG's response sounded skeptical of the possibility of a signal processor on WindowsRT, and I have to admit I don't know much about WindowsRT either. But we know you will have javascript available.  It sounds like you are interested in Digital Signal Processing in Javascript.  If you take a look at these resources. They could get you pointed in the right direction.

https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js

http://www.bores.com/courses/intro/index.htm

http://arc.id.au/SpectrumAnalyser.html